# Excel VBA updating graph data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

I have several charts referencing off one particular dataset. Each chart has a different number of series. Each series refer to one particular row of the dataset for a certain number of columns (ie. A1:Z1). During the update, I want to shift the data for all series by 1 column (ie. A1:Z1 -> B1:AA1). The column choice for all series will be the same.

My approach now is to go through all charts, in each chart count the number of series, for each series save the row number and update with the new columns.

My trouble is at retrieving the row number. I tried doing

```
foo = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
```

with the intention of extracting the row number from the string (which admittedly is not elegant), but the Values property does not return a string, even though when setting it, it does take in a string, ie:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Data!$A$1:$Z$1"
```

What would the best approach be? Should I just use a dynamically named range for each series?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Named Ranges?  That seems like it would be considerably easier than dealing with VBA.  Also, Is your data an Excel Table or just filled cells?

Comment: I am looking to dynamic named ranges now. Unfortunately my data is not a Table as the headers are on column A rather than row 1, and that I prefer to keep the data that way.

Comment: Managed to forgo VBA and use dynamic named ranges instead. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.  You should add what you did as an answer and mark it accepted so others that find this question can get an idea on how to solve similar issues.